# Mellin transform and equality of two functions

Tags: laplace-transform

If say, $\mathcal{M}f(s) = \mathcal{M}g(s)$ in a strip say $0 < a < \Re(s) < b$, then can we say that $f$ and $g$ are identical? Does the Mellin inversion theorem imply this?

Comment: i think so with equality upto "almost everywhere" like in fourier transform